# How to enter full screen in WKWebView iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, wkwebview, fullscreen

I have a `WKWebView` to open web pages. On a web page, there is an image which has fullscreen button.

On clicking on fullscreen button, image should enter in full screen mode, and when image is in fullscreen mode, then on clicking the same button image should exit from fullscreen mode.

It is working fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in `WKWebView`.

How can it be achieved for `WKWebView`?

Comment: I tried this URL(https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/gallery/) and fullscreen does work on WKWebView.

Comment: Yes, the above URL worked for me as well.

Comment: But I am not getting the reason behind why it is not happening in following URL :- https://docsviewer.electricaltraining.info/viewer/109

Comment: If you are thinking specifically about an image, should design and test for both notched and no-notched screens.. in this case, did you want to image to fill the safe area, or the entire physical screen?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkpreferences/3917769-iselementfullscreenenabled/

You can do it like below code.

```swift
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true
```

Although this site is written in Japanese, it's also useful.
https://techandmake.hatenablog.com/